# The German's are Experimenting

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Could I BE any more riddle.

your holiday starts, forget happiness
no out from these mates of no friendliness
your past is what we think
as space tortures, beginning to shrink

follow the sheep of fashion
through halls of no compassion
little sun is gained through wreck
each day it steals, the doves doth peck

Comment: First of all, you should stat the 'riddle' you are trying to solve, even if it is just a "what am I" type of riddle. Second, "Germans" is the plural of "German", and I don't think you're trying to go for a posessive noun.

Comment: @Zibbobz congratulations on getting the possesion idea. I can if it pleases you ask what am I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title made me think of

> Auschwitz (or just a generic Nazi concentration camp),

and I think I can get this to fit most of the riddle itself too. In fact, the following more general answer also works:

> PRISON.

*your holiday starts, forget happiness*

> Entering a prison is like a 'holiday' from the outside world, but you'll find no happiness there.

*no out from these mates of no friendliness*

> You cannot escape, and the guards will show you no friendliness.

*your past is what we think*

> People are imprisoned for crimes committed in their past.

*as space tortures, beginning to shrink*

> People in prison are confined in tiny spaces.

*follow the sheep of fashion*

> They're all dressed identically.

*through halls of no compassion*

> There isn't much compassion to be found in a prison.

*little sun is gained through wreck*

> People are shut away inside so they couldn't see the sun.

*each day it steals, the doves doth peck*

> Days in your life steal away uselessly. Doves are a symbol of peace, pecking away at the tyranny of prison.

Comment: "Follow the sheep of fashion" could be a (very dark) reference the uniforms they were forced to wear...

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure, but I think you are:

> **facial plastic surgery**

The German's are Experimenting

> with a practice in Berlin, [Jacques Joseph](http://www.aafprs.org/patient/about_us/h_father.html) is considered the father of modern facial plastic surgery

your holiday starts, forget happiness, no out from these mates of no friendliness

> many people now take vacations for plastic surgery (to Brazil, Thailand, South Africa, etc)

your past is what we think as space tortures, beginning to shrink

> shrinking and tightening skin is usually the objective

follow the sheep of fashion through halls of no compassion
little sun is gained through wreck each day it steals, the doves doth peck

> "wrecking" is done before reconstruction and sunlight is to be avoided

Answer (score 0):

I think I have an idea :)

> A birthday!

Holiday from happiness:

> Happy Birthday

Your past is what we think

> Each year we celebrate this day usually with reminders of the past year

As space tortures, beginning to shrink:

> Birth process. Contractions?

That's about all I can piece together.

Comment: I do like the answer, it is a positive view. Are you saying that a birthday is a holiday from happiness, rather than a holiday to happiness>

Comment: Of course birthdays are holidays from happiness! Most joyous occasion when a child is born